# Find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left({\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

This question comes from "adjusting the order of an infinite series".

We are talking about whether a series' value would change or not by changing the position of some terms.
For example, we have

$$\ln{2}=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left({\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}}\right)$$

By changing the order, we get

$$H=1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots$$

and
$$H=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left({\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}}\right)$$

And to generalize, we construct a series which has firstly, k positive terms and then 1 negative term, and the same story repeats. We write it as $H_{k}$.

But how to calculate the values of all these $H_{k}$ becomes a problem, in fact, I'm stuck in $H_{2}$.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Try computing $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{3k}{\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}}$ by collecting the positive terms and the negative terms.  It's easy to see that this equals $H$.

Answer (score 3):

We can compte the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\left({\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}}\right)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{1}{4n-3}=\frac{1}{4} \left(\psi \left(p+\frac{1}{4}\right)-\psi   \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{1}{4n-1}=\frac{1}{4} \left(\psi \left(p+\frac{3}{4}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}H_p$$ Summing and going from the polygamma to generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_p=\frac{1}{2} \left(H_{2 p-\frac{1}{2}}-H_p+2\log (2)\right)$$ Using asymptotics
$$S_p=\frac{3}{2}\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 p}+\frac{3}{64
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Write
$${1\over4n-3}+{1\over4n-1}-{1\over2n}={3\over 4n(4n-3)}+{1\over4n(4n-1)}\ .$$
Mathematica can sum both terms on the RHS, and obtains
$${1\over8}(\pi+6\log2)+{1\over8}(-\pi+2\log8)={3\over2}\log 2\ .$$

Comment: A very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited after the solution of @Christian Blatter:**

Let $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{4n-3}+ \frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n} \right)~~~~(1)$$
Let (1) be re-written as $S=S_1+S_2$
$$S_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n} \right), ~S_2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{4n} \right) $$
In both  cases we have difference of TWO divergent series  and the divergence will cancel out appropriately.
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1} [t^{4n-4}- t^{4n-1}] dt=\int_{0}^{1}\left( \frac{1}{1-t^4}-\frac{t^3}{1-t^4}\right) dt= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-t^3}{1-t^4} dt$$
$$\implies S_1=\int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{1}{2(1+t)}+\frac{1}{2(1+t^2)}+\frac{t}{2(1+t^2)}\right) dt=\frac{1}{2}\ln 2+\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{4}\ln 2.$$
Similarly,
$$ S_2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} [t^{4n-2}-t^{4n-1}] dt=\int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{t^2}{1-t^4}-\frac{t^3}{1-t^4}\right) dt= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^2-t^3}{1-t^4} dt$$
$$\implies S_2= \int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{1}{2(1+t)}-\frac{1}{2(1+t^2)}+\frac{t}{1+t^2}\right) =\frac{1}{2}\ln 2-\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{4}\ln 2.$$
So finally, we get $$S=\frac{3}{2} \ln 2$$

Comment: Could you please write out a few sentences explaining what is going on here? For example, why can you switch the integral and the limit?

Comment: emmm……I'm wondering why we could exchange the summation and the integral.

Comment: I have edited my answer, you may see it now. Thanks

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff You may find  my edited answer more appropriate and correct.

Answer (score 0):

For finite upper bound of the summation there exist for each summand a well known presentation:

S_N=

1/4 (-PolyGamma[0, 1/4] + PolyGamma[0, 1/4 + N])

-1/4 (-PolyGamma[0, 3/4] + PolyGamma[0, 3/4 + N])

+HarmonicNumber[N]/2

The PolyGamme function with 0 at the first argument are HarmonicNumber functions.

Evidently, these do not compensate to zero. So there remains some HarmonicNumber behavoir in the solution for very large `N`.

[image: Log is a minor criteria function to the HarmonicNumber function].

This part must vanish to give a finite solution, but

[image]

For N-> infinity use an asymptotic series expansion:

Log[8]/2=3Log[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRfDe.png)/2